# RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state

Tags: node.js, tedious

This error message (message in headline) has been haunting me from time to time. Usually, it doesn't show up, but sometimes when user logs in, the program crashes and that error shows up.

Full error message here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXxZ7.png

I have searched Tedious Api and tried to use event requestCompleted but was unsuccessful.

My Node.js

```js
        // Post method of Login
        app.post('/Login', urlencodedParser, (request, response) => {
            DBConnect.Login(request.body.email, request.body.password, connection, (error, results, fields) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Error: Cannot login: " + error);
                    response.send("Error Try again");

                } else {
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        if (results[0].Email == request.body.email && results[0].Password == (crypto.createHash("SHA256").update(request.body.password).digest("hex"))) {
                            console.log(results[0].ID);
                            response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(results[0].ID));
                        } else {
                            response.status(401).send("Login failed: wrong userame or password.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        response.status(401).send("Login failed: wrong userame or password.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

My login request;

```js
let Login = (Email, Password, connection, callback) => {

    var request = new Request('SELECT Email, Password, ID FROM Users WHERE Email=@Email', function (error, rowCount, rows) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("request error: " + error);
            } else {

                results = createResults(rows);
                console.log(results[0]);             
                callback(error, results, null)
            }
        });
    request.addParameter('Email', TYPES.NVarChar, Email);
    connection.execSql(request);

}

I except login system to work, but sometimes it throws me that error.
```